# Can I unzip downloaded zipped shapefiles into memory for upload into database?

Tags: python, memory, subprocess, zip, postgis

I'm trying to extract open data zips from a public website into a postgis database I'm hosting locally. I'm using BytesIO to try to stream the individual shapefiles into a postgis command called shp2pgsql but getting an error that the individual .dbf files are not available from the command line tool. Is there a more appropriate way to pull the zips, extract them into memory, and upload to a postgresql/postgis database? See code and error below:
Code Block

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen
import subprocess
# or: requests.get(url).content

count = 0
resp = urlopen("some/website/files.zip")
zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
for file in zipfile.namelist():
    if file.endswith('.shp'):
        count += 1
        cmd = 'shp2pgsql -s 4326 {0} temp_table_{1} | PGPASSWORD=somepassword psql -h someip -p 5432 -d somedb -U someuser -q'.format(file, count)
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Error message

> Unable to open some_directory_shp/some_shp1.shp or some_directory_shp/some_shp1.SHP.
> some_directory_shp/some_shp1.shp: dbf file (.dbf) can not be opened.

Comment: I don't know `shp2pgsql`  but it is external program and will not work with data in memory created in Python. It needs file on disk because it needs filename as paramater. You may only check if it has option to read data from stream and then maybe you could do something like `echo stream | shp2pgsql ... | ...` using `stdin` in `subprocess`. BTW: some programs may use `-` instead of filename and then they read from `stdin` but it has to be describe in program's help (documentation)

Comment: the simples solution is to write it in file on disk